Why does the whole house fan run on high regardless of the high/low switch position
New whole house fan motor installed with high/low capability. When connected to the high/low switch the fan only runs on high speed regardless of which speed level is chosen. Switch was removed and wiring was connected to the low speed function but ran at high speed. Any trouble shooting suggestions.

Model number of fan and switch?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
